# How to call Fragment inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I  have created a fragment, and used this inside another Fragment layout.

This is the XML of my layout.

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wv_facebook"
    >

</WebView>


<fragment
    class="com.loading.LoadingAnimation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/wv_facebook_loadingAnimation"

    />
```

Now i want to get the ID of this `fragment`. I used following procedure but i am getting `incompatible type` error message.

```
Loading Animation loadingAnimation;

 loadingAnimation = (LoadingAnimation) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.wv_facebook_loadingAnimation);
```

> Required `LoadingAnimation` Found android.support.v4.app.fragment

Comment: you can cast it `loadingAnimation = (LoadingAnimation) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.wv_facebook_loadingAnimation);`

Comment: I am getting same error message

Comment: what your `LoadingAnimation` extends to? `android.app.Fragment` or `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try below sample too:

```
DashboardFragment innerFragment = new DashboardFragment();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                innerFragment .setEnterTransition(new Slide(Gravity.RIGHT));
                innerFragment .setExitTransition(new Slide(Gravity.LEFT));
            }


            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                folderName = mFileList.get(position).getName();

                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, innerFragment, folderName);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(folderName);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
```